# Apache Spark: NPE during restoring state from checkpoint

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

We are building simple Streaming application that uses HBase RDD to join with incoming DStream.
Sample code:

```
val indexState = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
  conf,
  classOf[TableInputFormat],
  classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],
  classOf[Result]).map { case (rowkey, v) => //some logic}

val result = dStream.transform { rdd =>
  rdd.leftOuterJoin(indexState)
}
```

It works fine, but when we enable checkpointing for the StreamingContext 
and let the application to recover from a previously created checkpoint, 
it always throws NullPointerException.

```
ERROR streaming.StreamingContext: Error starting the context, marking it as stopped
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.setConf(TableInputFormat.java:119)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
```

Has anybody faced the same issues?
Versions:

- Spark 1.6.x
- Hadoop 2.7.x

Thanks!

Comment: When you say 'previously created checkpoint' does that mean the streaming job was stopped and resubmitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark Streaming checkpoints cannot be used to recover from previous jobs, at least in 1.6.x. If your job is stopped and re-submitted, the checkpoint data cannot be re-used. You'll have to delete any old checkpoint data before submitting the job.

> [R]estarting from earlier checkpoint information of pre-upgrade code cannot be done. The checkpoint information essentially contains serialized Scala/Java/Python objects and trying to deserialize objects with new, modified classes may lead to errors. In this case, either start the upgraded app with a different checkpoint directory, or delete the previous checkpoint directory.

[Upgrading the code - checkpointing](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/streaming-programming-guide.html#upgrading-application-code)

Comment: Does it mean that checkpoints works only for dstream and we can not use them when working with any side rdd?

Comment: Your usage is fine, but checkpointing allows driver recovery, it doesn't support stopping and starting the whole streaming job via spark-submit.

Comment: *I found that the same also held when just restarting the streaming job without any code changes* That is incorrect. There is no problem restarting a failed job with existing data as long as no changes were made.

Comment: Hmm it is possible that it was user error, or my recollection is poor.  I'll remove that paragraph so as not to inadvertently mislead.